# Prove that the inverse of the inverse of a matrix A is equal to A

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

I've written a proof of $ (A^{-1})^{-1} = A $, but I'm worried it's a circular argument.
Please let me know if this is solid. I would also be interested if you have any other proofs of this property. I've seen ones on here that say the property follows directly from the definition of the inverse, but I don't see how.

 
Proof: 
By definition, B is the inverse of A if and only if AB = I and BA = I.

Observe, 
$ (A^{-1})^{-1} = A $ 
$ (A^{-1})^{-1}B = AB $ 
$ (A^{-1})^{-1}B = I $ 
And 
$ (A^{-1})^{-1} = A $ 
$ B(A^{-1})^{-1} = BA $ 
$ B(A^{-1})^{-1} = I $ 

Thus, $ (A^{-1})^{-1} = A $

Comment: You can’t start with the thing you’re trying to prove. You don’t even know that $(A^{-1})^{-1}$ exists to begin with. Start with what you know about A and $A^{-1}$

Comment: "Let $A$ be given and let $B = A^{-1}$ so that $AB = I$ and $BA = I$.  By definition, if there is a $C$ such that $BC = I$ and $CB = I$ then $C = B^{-1} = (A^{-1})^{-1}$.  Note that $C = \dots$ works ...".

Comment: There is a typo in your title, please fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, $B$ is the inverse of $A$ if and only if $AB = I$ and $BA = I$.

Observe that $A^{-1}A=I$ and $AA^{-1}=I$.
So the inverse of $A^{-1}$ is $A$.